# Association names on ends without navigability?

Tags: associations, uml, class-diagram

I have a question regarding UML Class diagrams.

I know I can just use one name which refers to both sides but my question is:

Is it necessary to show association names at both sides of an association when it is uni directional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Association ends are properties (i.e., "variables"). When a class owns a property and the property is unnamed, that could be a problem. In contrast, when an association owns an unnamed property, that's not really a problem. You don't need to specify a name for association-owned properties.

Here's an example. I've made MagicDraw show association-end properties as attributes as well, just to make a point:

[image]

Notice how `theB` shows up as a property in class `A` and at the end of the association with class `B`. That's because they are two different ways of showing the same property. (It's a special way of showing association-end properties that we normally don't turn on in the tool.) Also notice how class `C` has an *unnamed* property inside the box and at the end of the association with class `A`. Again, that's two different ways to show the same property. How would you implement that unnamed property in a programming language? That could be a problem, right?

Another thing to notice is that class `B` does not have an attribute called `theA`, and class `A` does not have an attribute called `theC`. That's because those properties are non-navigable and the *associations* own those properties.

Conflating navigability and property ownership has become deprecated in UML. Recently, the UML spec introduced "association dot notation" to indicate property ownership. (A dot at the end means the class owns the property.) Personally, I never had a problem with the conflation, and I hate the new dot notation. Many tools do not support it, and I think it's downright ugly. Moreover, a diagram that has no dots on it is ambiguous. You can't tell whether it was drawn before or after dots were introduced to the spec!

Comment: I just skimmed the latest specs and it seems that 2.5 introduced the dot-notation. I can't tell I like it either, but OMG does not care. Enterprise Architect had it all of a sudden and it's a PITA to turn it on/off while some operations let it pop up out of nothing.

Comment: @ThomasKilian They fixed the problem with the dots in one of the latest builds. (1226 or something like that)

Comment: @GeertBellekens I guess, just the "moving ends" issue. Not where they placed the property which is (has been?) buried deeply.

Comment: In MagicDraw there's a toggle under general project options to enable the dot notation for associations. Does Sparx do that too?

Comment: I'm new to class diagrams and UML in general so your answer doesn't make a lot of sense to me but thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Porteous96: I can clarify if you tell me what doesn't makes sense to you.

Comment: @Porteous96: I tried to anticipate what might be confusing and clarify. Let me know how well I did.

Comment: Jim, in EA you have a lot of properties per connector and they are grouped. The Owned property is accessed by 1) opening the properties dialog 2) clicking Roles 3) +open Advanced (per side) 4) scroll up 5) select True/False from the dropdown at Owned at the very bottom. User friendly is something else.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: Yikes!

Comment: Your diagram helped thanks. I understand about the unnamed properties and why that's a problem, obviously. I'm still unsure of my question though as if for example class A has an arrow pointing to class B then this means the class A knows about class B but not the other way around. So can I just add the one association name like in your example where you've put theB and miss out theA?

Comment: Yes, you can leave off `theA`. That name doesn't matter. It is non-navigable _and_ it is not present in class `B`. That's why it is not shown in the attribute compartment. Does that answer the lingering question?

Comment: I tweaked the answer to cover naming association-owned properties. I hope that helps.